# How to set different cropped images in different imageviews

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I add 1st image it gets cropped and get displayed into 1st Image View, but when I add 2nd image it override 1st image present in 1st Image View instead it should display in 2nd Image View.

[Problem is shown here](https://filebin.net/ev0c8tih9drjt9vz/WhatsApp_Video_2020-02-06_at_2.59.11_PM.mp4?t=moyg7bjk)

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode== 0  && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() !=null){
        Imageuri = data.getData();
        CropImage.activity(Imageuri).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).start(AddaddNewProductActivity.this);
    }
    else if (requestCode== 1  && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() !=null){
        Imageuri = data.getData();
        CropImage.activity(Imageuri).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).start(AddaddNewProductActivity.this);
    }
    else if (requestCode== 2  && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() !=null){
        Imageuri = data.getData();
        CropImage.activity(Imageuri).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).start(AddaddNewProductActivity.this);
    }

    if ( requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
        Image.setBackground(null);
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        croppedImageUri = result.getUri();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), croppedImageUri);
            Image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
private void showImageChooser(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 0);
    }

    private void showImageChooser1(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 1);
    }

    private void showImageChooser2(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 2);
    }
```

Comment: Show your CropImage File code

Comment: cropimage is not a method its a github library

Comment: @Vickyexpert https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper -- link to the library

Comment: @Vickyexpert please help

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set all images in one image view only, therefor this issue is creating, I have made some changes in your code, please check below weather it is working or not.

```
// First declare one variable to identify which imageview is clicked
int currentSelectedImage = 0;


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if ((requestCode == 0 || requestCode == 1 || requestCode == 2) && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() !=null){
        currentSelectedImage = requestCode;
        Imageuri = data.getData();
        CropImage.activity(Imageuri).setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON).start(AddaddNewProductActivity.this);
    }

    if ( requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){

        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        croppedImageUri = result.getUri();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), croppedImageUri);

            if(currentSelectedImage == 0)
            {
                Image.setBackground(null);
                Image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            else if(currentSelectedImage == 1)
            {
                Image1.setBackground(null);
                Image1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            else if(currentSelectedImage == 2)
            {
                Image2.setBackground(null);
                Image2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Enjoy your coding